# Using a PHP for loop to display repeating nodes from a huge external XML feed

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

I've been at this problem for a week or so and haven't found any information in already exiting questions that have lead to a solution.  I am pulling in a very large XML file from a company (it's a MITS Feed) that easily tops a million lines of output.  I unfortunately can not give the location of this file due to legal reasons, but i'll explain what I'm trying to do and maybe you all can help me put this issue to rest.

I'm calling in the file as such:

```
<?php 

$xml=simplexml_load_file("location-of-file/feed.xml");

?>
```

After this I want to run through and pull out pieces of information for each property.  Here is the exact schema we are using -

http://www.mitsproject.com/Content/ServeFile.cfm?FileID=4075

I've tried importing this as a DOMDocument and traversing through the XML that way, but have had no luck.  Possibly just an example of how to pull all of the Property nodes in a PHP for loop would be the bomb.  Thank you in advance.

P.S. I know the file is at least being grabbed, because when I run -

```
<?php 

$xml = simplexml_load_file("location-of-file/feed.xml", null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
print_r($xml);

?>
```

I am getting an insanely large output.

UPDATE:

Here is an example of one 'Property' as a SimpleXMLElement, maybe this will help -

```
[111] => SimpleXMLElement Object
```

(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [IDValue] => 56bce392-b9fb-4290-97bc-900b9ebf9a1e
        )

```
[PropertyID] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Identification] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [IDValue] => 56bce392-b9fb-4290-97bc-900b9ebf9a1e
                                [OrganizationName] => rentershq
                                [IDType] => property
                            )

                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [IDValue] => 1a47b013fa94796a8973a23cc8b01192ba603460
                                [OrganizationName] => rentershq
                                [IDType] => Company
                            )

                    )

            )

        [MarketingName] => Clean Older Unit
        [WebSite] => http://rentershq.appfolio.com/listings/listings/56bce392-b9fb-4290-97bc-900b9ebf9a1e
        [Address] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [AddressType] => property
                    )

                [Description] => Address of Available Listing
                [AddressLine1] => 2850 PIONEER DRIVE - 17 
                [City] => REDDING
                [State] => CA
                [PostalCode] => 96001
                [Country] => US
            )

        [Phone] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [PhoneType] => office
                    )

                [PhoneNumber] => (530) 722-0800
            )

        [Email] => james@rentershq.com
    )

[ILS_Identification] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [ILS_IdentificationType] => Apartment
                [RentalType] => Market Rate
            )

        [Latitude] => 40.5873599
        [Longitude] => -122.41376
        [LastUpdate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Month] => 12
                        [Day] => 4
                        [Year] => 2013
                    )

            )

    )

[Information] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [StructureType] => Standard
        [UnitCount] => 1
        [ShortDescription] => Clean Older Unit
        [LongDescription] => Please drive by property. Please contact onsite manager Joe Skeen to view inside of unit. 530-255-8375 
        [Rents] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [StandardRent] => 500.00
            )

        [PropertyAvailabilityURL] => http://rentershq.appfolio.com/listings/listings/56bce392-b9fb-4290-97bc-900b9ebf9a1e
    )

[Fee] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [ProrateType] => Standard
        [LateType] => Standard
        [LatePercent] => 0
        [LateMinFee] => 0
        [LateFeePerDay] => 0
        [NonRefundableHoldFee] => 0
        [AdminFee] => 0
        [ApplicationFee] => 15.00
        [BrokerFee] => 0
    )

[Deposit] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [DepositType] => Security Deposit
            )

        [Amount] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [AmountType] => Actual
                    )

                [ValueRange] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [Exact] => 700.00
                                [Currency] => USD
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[Policy] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Pet] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Allowed] => false
                    )

            )

    )

[Phase] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [IDValue] => 56bce392-b9fb-4290-97bc-900b9ebf9a1e
            )

        [Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [Description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [UnitCount] => 1
        [RentableUnits] => 1
        [TotalSquareFeet] => 625
        [RentableSquareFeet] => 625
    )

[Building] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [IDValue] => 56bce392-b9fb-4290-97bc-900b9ebf9a1e
            )

        [Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [Description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [UnitCount] => 1
        [SquareFeet] => 625
    )

[Floorplan] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [IDValue] => 56bce392-b9fb-4290-97bc-900b9ebf9a1e
            )

        [Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [UnitCount] => 1
        [Room] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [RoomType] => Bedroom
                            )

                        [Count] => 2
                        [Comment] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [RoomType] => Bathroom
                            )

                        [Count] => 1
                        [Comment] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [SquareFeet] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Min] => 625
                        [Max] => 625
                    )

            )

        [MarketRent] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Min] => 500
                        [Max] => 500
                    )

            )

        [EffectiveRent] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Min] => 500
                        [Max] => 500
                    )

            )

    )

[ILS_Unit] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [IDValue] => 56bce392-b9fb-4290-97bc-900b9ebf9a1e
            )

        [Units] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [Unit] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [Identification] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [IDValue] => 56bce392-b9fb-4290-97bc-900b9ebf9a1e
                                        [OrganizationName] => RentersHQ
                                    )

                            )

                        [MarketingName] => Clean Older Unit
                        [UnitBedrooms] => 2
                        [UnitBathrooms] => 1.0
                        [MinSquareFeet] => 625
                        [MaxSquareFeet] => 625
                        [SquareFootType] => internal
                        [UnitRent] => 500.00
                        [MarketRent] => 500.00
                        [Address] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [@attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [AddressType] => property
                                    )

                                [AddressLine1] => 2850 PIONEER DRIVE - 17 
                                [City] => REDDING
                                [PostalCode] => 96001
                                [Country] => US
                            )

                    )

            )

        [Availability] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [VacateDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [Month] => 7
                                [Day] => 26
                                [Year] => 2013
                            )

                    )

                [VacancyClass] => Unoccupied
                [MadeReadyDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [Month] => 7
                                [Day] => 26
                                [Year] => 2013
                            )

                    )

            )

        [Amenity] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Other
                            )

                        [Description] => Ground Level Apartment
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Other
                            )

                        [Description] => HUD Considered
                    )

                [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Other
                            )

                        [Description] => Month-to-Month Lease
                    )

                [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Other
                            )

                        [Description] => Credit Check Required
                    )

                [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Other
                            )

                        [Description] => Stove
                    )

                [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Other
                            )

                        [Description] => Window Coverings
                    )

                [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Carpet
                            )

                        [Description] => Tille and Carpet
                    )

                [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Other
                            )

                        [Description] => Off Street Parking
                    )

                [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Dryer
                            )

                        [Description] => Coin-Op Washer / Dryer
                    )

                [9] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Washer
                            )

                        [Description] => Coin-Op Washer / Dryer
                    )

                [10] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Refrigerator
                            )

                        [Description] => Refrigerator
                    )

                [11] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => DishWasher
                            )

                        [Description] => Dishwasher
                    )

                [12] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Washer
                            )

                        [Description] => Dishwasher
                    )

                [13] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Disposal
                            )

                        [Description] => Garbage Disposal
                    )

                [14] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Heat
                            )

                        [Description] => Elec. Heating
                    )

                [15] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Other
                            )

                        [Description] => Window Cooler
                    )

                [16] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Other
                            )

                        [Description] => Dog Not Allowed
                    )

                [17] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [AmenityType] => Other
                            )

                        [Description] => Cat Not Allowed
                    )

            )

    )

[File] => Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Active] => true
                        [FileID] => 809492874
                    )

                [FileType] => Photo
                [Description] => Unit Photo
                [Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [Caption] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [Format] => image/jpeg
                [Src] => http://pa.cdn.appfolio.com/rentershq/images/8ed6dbf4-36cf-47e4-b519-7783bea727dc/medium.jpg
                [Width] => 1280
                [Height] => 960
                [Rank] => 1
            )

        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Active] => true
                        [FileID] => 809492885
                    )

                [FileType] => Photo
                [Description] => Unit Photo
                [Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [Caption] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [Format] => image/jpeg
                [Src] => http://pa.cdn.appfolio.com/rentershq/images/9b6b35e7-0ca1-4c20-a396-4be6fb21bf80/medium.jpg
                [Width] => 1280
                [Height] => 960
                [Rank] => 2
            )

        [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Active] => true
                        [FileID] => 809492887
                    )

                [FileType] => Photo
                [Description] => Unit Photo
                [Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [Caption] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [Format] => image/jpeg
                [Src] => http://pa.cdn.appfolio.com/rentershq/images/c6ab69e3-0787-4221-893d-fbd982c2a3bd/medium.jpg
                [Width] => 1280
                [Height] => 960
                [Rank] => 3
            )

        [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Active] => true
                        [FileID] => 809492889
                    )

                [FileType] => Photo
                [Description] => Unit Photo
                [Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [Caption] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [Format] => image/jpeg
                [Src] => http://pa.cdn.appfolio.com/rentershq/images/6ac14176-73c3-452b-80ae-b41820887c73/medium.jpg
                [Width] => 1280
                [Height] => 960
                [Rank] => 4
            )

        [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Active] => true
                        [FileID] => 809492892
                    )

                [FileType] => Photo
                [Description] => Unit Photo
                [Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [Caption] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [Format] => image/jpeg
                [Src] => http://pa.cdn.appfolio.com/rentershq/images/252a2ae1-66ea-471d-8cf1-48e795add81d/medium.jpg
                [Width] => 960
                [Height] => 1280
                [Rank] => 5
            )

        [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [@attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [Active] => true
                        [FileID] => 809492895
                    )

                [FileType] => Photo
                [Description] => Unit Photo
                [Name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [Caption] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

                [Format] => image/jpeg
                [Src] => http://pa.cdn.appfolio.com/rentershq/images/b93c93f6-b571-4a33-a4e3-e0ac663679bc/medium.jpg
                [Width] => 1280
                [Height] => 960
                [Rank] => 6
            )

    )
```

)

Comment: what do you mean you've had no luck?

Comment: I'm unable to grab the data I want from specific nodes within the SimpleXML elements.  (I'm a RoR dev, so adjusting to the PHP syntax is likely a large stumbling block as well - I'm sure my issue is something idiotic)

Comment: have you used the following http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createprocessinginstruction.php

Comment: Going to work through that now, I'll be back with an update shortly. Thank you for the direction, Liam.

Comment: No problem at all, not sure the link will actually help though i think i misread it

Comment: Okay, so that creates an XML file.  My problem is getting the existing information from the already existing XML file stored on another company's server to be accessible in a way so that I can run a query on it and display only the information of my choosing.

Comment: can you give us an example of what the node is called? or see if you can take a snipet from the feed and use that as a tester? are you getting any timeout errors in your apache log?

Comment: I added a new section to the question under "UPDATE:"

Comment: can you post your php code for pulling the results aswell?

Comment: that is simply through <?php 

$xml = simplexml_load_file("location-of-file/feed.xml", null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
print_r($xml);

?>

Comment: And what do you want to do with the data? manipulate it and output it? process it?

Comment: I want to output the data after selecting certain properties based on /Property->PropertyID->Identification->OrganizationName -- pulling only the properties which match to a specific organization

Comment: well print_r will just output the datatype and result of the XML that has been parsed as an array. You will need the following. to access an element you would do echo $xml->PropertyID->WebSite; to echo out the website name obveously you would need to loop through the individual nodes. However as the items returned are Objects don't use foreach($xml as $item){ echo $item['PropertyID']; } as this will bring up an error that the entity is an object and needs to be accessed directly using the ->

Comment: so what would you suggest as a way to loop through the objects?

Comment: If it's a very large XML file, you probably want to use [XMLReader](http://php.net/xmlreader) to parse it as a stream, rather than loading it all into memory in one go. Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/hubgit/7336826

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend something similar to this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("location-of-file/feed.xml", null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

foreach($xml as $key => $item){
  // to select an element do something like this
  $item->WebSite;
}
```

however please note that $item is a copy of the array $xml so to manipulate this object you will need to change $item to &$item or you will need to manipulate the actual value as such in your loop

```
$test = $item->WebSite;
//do something to $test
$xml->$key->WebSite = $test;
```

if however you are building a new array/xml document you don't need to worry about this issue

Update:

I have tested this on an example feed and you should be able to get this too work with a little editing

```
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml", null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$values = array("Belgian Waffles","French Toast");
$new = new SimpleXMLElement("<tester></tester>");
foreach($xml->food as $item){
    if(in_array($item->name,$values)){
        $type = $new->addChild('type');
        $movie = $type->addChild('movie');
        $movie->addChild('price', $item->price);
    }else{
    }
}
echo $new->asXML();
```

basically give this ago, edit it to use the right nodes and build the feed right for you then this should work. the asXML() has a optional parameter you can pass in to write the file
so changing `echo $new->asXML();` to `$new->asXML("test.xml");` will instead write the file to test.xml instead of outputting the data. if you do save it make sure you get rid of `header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");`

Comment: Does displaying this information through the loop count as manipulating it? I unfortunately have to pull from the direct feed as it is updated every 30 minutes and building a new XML document doesn't make sense (to me - please correct me if there is value in this, I'm here to learn).

Comment: @NoahNathaniel-DanielDavis it depends entirely on if you only want to display certain nodes, if you do then you will need to build from the XML feed. However if it is the entire feed you may aswel grab the data using http://www.php.net/file_get_contents as this will pull the data each time. A better way is to us the php file to create the xml document using file_get_contents and run a cron job every 30 minutes to create a new XML file.

Comment: I am only wanting to grab the 'property' nodes and more specifically only the 'property' nodes with 'propertyid->identification->organizationname' that matches to a list of specific strings (or organizationnames)  I'm still not having any success in achieving this :(

Comment: @NoahNathaniel-DanielDavis i have updated my answer at the bottom, try that

Comment: Hey Liam, I am trying this now.  If I don't find success in the next hour or so, is it possible to get you to sign an NDA and hire you for a short freelance job?

Comment: @NoahNathaniel-DanielDavis If you want help then yeah no problem but i could do it for you. Not sure how to do that with out breaking SO terms though

Comment: I am unsure as well, there's no way to PM is there?

Comment: can't find the email, go ahead and accept the request if you'd like, it's looking like we'll need to head in that direction and moving quicker is a priority :)

Answer (score 1):

try outputting the feed using

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($feed);
echo '</pre>';
```

This should give you a much 'prettier' view of the scheme and what nodes are/aren't accessible!

Comment: This did create a much 'happier' view of the scheme and nodes! Thank you!